# April Fools Day!

Tags: popularity-contest, sequence, date, underhanded

Your challenge is simple: write a program or function which appears to print the first ten numbers of any integer sequence (on OEIS, the answerer may choose which sequence), but instead prints the exact text:

```
Happy April Fool's Day!
```

if and only if it is run on April 1st of any year. Run on any other day should make it output its original output. (Unfortunately, I was a little late posting this challenge). Answers should be voted up for clever hiding of the April fools part.

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the most votes on May 8th wins!

Comment: I really liked this challenge until I got to this part `if and only if it is run on April 1st of any year. Run on any other day should make it output its original output.` Can I take an input for currentDate or something?

Comment: Hiding code within other code makes this an underhanded challenge, and these are [no longer welcome on the site](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8326/20260). Moreover, "most creative" popularity contests lack an objective winning criterion and have fallen out of favor.

Comment: This challenge is [tag:underhanded], and such challenges are no longer on-topic.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Huh? It looks more like a [tag:decision-problem] to me.

Comment: @SIGSEGV Also a [tag:decision-problem], and not [tag:kolmogorov-complexity], but challenges that ask for answers which appear to do something else than what they really do are [tag:underhanded].

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No, It's just one answer which does things the 'underhanded' way.

Comment: Underhanded challenges are off-topic per [community consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8326/12012).

Comment: Any ideas on how I can rewrite this question to be on-topic? Maybe make it a code-golf?

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE)

```
{1001,10,1}→LA
{1010,1,1}→LA
{1011,11,1}→LB
{1020,2,1}→LC
{1021,12,1}→LD
{1030,3,1}→LE
{1040,4,1}→LF
{1050,5,1}→LG
{1060,6,1}→LH
{1070,7,1}→LI

getDate→L1

IF L1(2)=LA(2) and L1(3)=LA(3):Then
"Happy October First!"
End
IF L1(2)=LB(2) and L1(3)=LB(3):Then
"Happy New Year!"
End
IF L1(2)=LC(2) and L1(3)=LC(3):Then
"Happy November First!"
End
IF L1(2)=LD(2) and L1(3)=LD(3):Then
"Happy February First!"
End
IF L1(2)=LE(2) and L1(3)=LE(3):Then
"Happy December First!"
End
IF L1(2)=LF(2) and L1(3)=LF(3):Then
"Happy March First!"
End
IF L1(2)=LG(2) and L1(3)=LG(3):Then
Disp "Happy April Fool's Day!"
Return:End
IF L1(2)=LH(2) and L1(3)=LH(3):Then
"Happy May First!"
End
IF L1(2)=LI(2) and L1(3)=LI(3):Then
"Happy June First!"
End
IF L1(2)=LJ(2) and L1(3)=LJ(3):Then
"Happy July First!"
End

ClrHome
Output(1,1,toString(10000LA(1)+100LA(2)+LA(3)))
Output(2,1,toString(10000LB(1)+100LB(2)+LB(3)))
Output(3,1,toString(10000LC(1)+100LC(2)+LC(3)))
Output(4,1,toString(10000LD(1)+100LD(2)+LD(3)))
Output(5,1,toString(10000LE(1)+100LE(2)+LE(3)))
Output(6,1,toString(10000LF(1)+100LF(2)+LF(3)))
Output(7,1,toString(10000LG(1)+100LG(2)+LG(3)))
Output(8,1,toString(10000LH(1)+100LH(2)+LH(3)))
Output(9,1,toString(10000LI(1)+100LI(2)+LI(3)))
Output(10,1,toString(10000LJ(1)+100LJ(2)+LJ(3)))
```

Uses [OEIS A210884](https://oeis.org/A210884).

Stores the numbers as dates and converts them on-the-fly to output. It even leaves you a message in `Ans` if today is one of the dates!

Comment: Nice one! You only display April fools and use other ones as a way to hide the sequence, right?

Comment: @SIGSEGV Yes, at first I was going to use Goto and have the label many many blank lines after the last Output to hide it, but that seemed a bit too obvious.

Comment: Well, I think I did corrupt too much on getting the month. See mine.

Comment: You can omit `)` or `}` at the end of a line or before `→`, if TI didn't decide to scrap that feature from the TI-84+CE. You can also remove the small L from the variable being stored when assigning a value to a list.

Answer (score 5):

## C

I use some fun CLANG properties to do tricky math and print the text sneakishly. I am printing the sequence of even numbers 0,2,4,6 etc up to 42.

This is a nice solution because I don't use any letters or hard coded strings, just pure math trickery to end up outputting the desired text even though it appears to a human brain that this should just be outputting 0,2,4,6,etc

[Try it online! (Just the sneaky April Fools Day version)](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#ldTPToNAEMfxszwFqTEputPuzC4w6Dv4DhW3sYdSrTZpND6250r/aFR@c5CEA4X9dvNh2V12fp/miy7lj@tF93K7Wd6l9XhbHC/n49FFO3L5tsiy5WzRjYv8LTvL8v6YTg9P5M/paZO6Nl3n3omLrnLq2DsWx3EymUT587w/XH396Wtar/JaqJbDzz/nIJf7m1e@uMl@BWQYKKkcDvfH8dKP39/71YjDBnul/rSmEVGmQpmqz1RWpkIZBRkO1J9WRlGGAa0IiUnLHmYQcKDSnAxDYgbGjVJjCjMk5uq/GUjMwFhr0trMQGIBxKqk5mwEEoughUOnF4gykFgAcawomqtPILEAYi1JSzMDiQURB1Jz3QgkDmiDUKpN4gCJAyCuyXzdAQIHAKxMymYGAgcA3H@XgwjxqQJ9A/ANnoK5aAL0jcC3rKk0aSL0jci3oboxM3gjRjsxMaA5befxWzh73@0@uhW1s/YhfQI)

```
#define printNumber(x) printf("%c", x)

main() {
    
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetLocalTime(&st);
    BOOL isFunDay = (st.wDay == 4 && st.wDay == 1);
    
    if (isFunDay) {
        printEvenNumbersTheFunWay();//fun way for a fun day!
    } else {
        printSomeEvenNumbersTheBoringWay();
    }
    
}

printEvenNumbersTheFunWay() {
    
    //print sequence: 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14...42
    
    //print 0
    #define zero 72-72
    printNumber(2*zero+0);

    //print 2
    #define zero 5-5
    printNumber(20*zero+2);
    
    //print 4
    #define zero 108-108
    printNumber(2*zero+4);
    
    //print 6
    #define zero 106-106
    printNumber(2*zero+6);
    
    //print 8
    #define zero 113-113
    printNumber(2*zero+8);
    
    //print 10
    #define zero 22-22
    printNumber(2*zero+10);
    
    //print 12
    #define zero 53-53
    printNumber(2*zero+12);
    
    //print 14
    #define zero 98-98
    printNumber(2*zero+14);
    
    //print 16
    #define zero 98-98
    printNumber(2*zero+16);
    
    //print 18
    #define zero 87-87
    printNumber(2*zero+18);
    
    //print 20
    #define zero 88-88
    printNumber(2*zero+20);
    
    //print 22
    #define zero 10-10
    printNumber(2*zero+22);
    
    //print 24
    #define zero 46-46
    printNumber(2*zero+24);
    
    //print 26
    #define zero 85-85
    printNumber(2*zero+26);
    
    //print 28
    #define zero 83-83
    printNumber(2*zero+28);
    
    //print 30
    #define zero 78-78
    printNumber(2*zero+30);
    
    //print 32
    #define zero 7-7
    printNumber(2*zero+32);
    
    //print 34
    #define zero 81-81
    printNumber(2*zero+34);
    
    //print 36
    #define zero 2-2
    printNumber(-1*zero+36);
    
    //print 38
    #define zero 30-30
    printNumber(2*zero+38);
    
    //print 40
    #define zero 57-57
    printNumber(2*zero+40);
    
    //print 42
    #define zero 79-79
    printNumber(2*zero+42);
    
    //print 44
    #define zero 1-1
    printNumber(-10*zero+44);
    
}

printSomeEvenNumbersTheBoringWay() {
    
    //print sequence: 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14...42
    
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 42) {
        printf("%i, ", i);
        i+=2;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same answer as your deleted one?

Comment: My deleted one used a BOOL for detecting date which was not valid for this competition so I posted this valid submission which actually checks system-time

Answer (score 4):

## JS, A000027

```js
d=new Date();
if(d.getMonth()+("")[(![]+"")[+[]]+"ontcol"+(!![]+[]["fi"+(![]+"")[!+[]+!+[]]+"l"])[10]+"r"]()[11]+("")["fon"+(!![]+"")[0]+"color"]()[11]+!+[]+!+[]*!+[]+!+[]&&d.getDate()==+!+[])alert("Happy April Fool's Day!");
else{for(i=0;i<10;)alert(++i);}
```

Mmm, good mixture of JS and JSF*ck. (Fun fact: The majority of the code is used to represent `==`.)

Good tip for corrupting code like mine: [JS to JSFuck Conversion code/list](https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck/blob/master/jsfuck.js)

Answer (score -2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027)

```python
import datetime as a
if(str(a.date.today())[5:]=='04-01'):print("Happy April Fool's Day!")
else:
 for i in range(10):print(i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NcvBCgIhEIDhu08x7UWHaFGoi7CHIKJ3iA4D68aAq6Jz8emtDh3/D/7Be8lVYCUJwnsAakCKN9OkGpp/PEteqRvE58W/lkXb88k6jb5UTmKmB5XS4fqtCPeco25wo36YUIXYglew5QoMnKBSegfj7H/lo8MxPg)